# Yii2: how to show data from two related tables?

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-select2, database-table, kartik-v

I have the table **persons(id_person, name_person, id_color)** and the table **colors(id_color, name_color)**.

I need to show names of the persons and the color name of every person inside a Select2 component.

I am using a Select2 component very similar to [kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2) and [2amigos/yii2-select2-widget](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-select2-widget).

I can do it creating an array with a SQL query but I would like to know if Yii2 provides a better and easy solution.

Comment: is it `one-to-one` or `one-to-many` relation with the `colors` table, means a person can have a single color assigned or multiple

Comment: It is one-to-many.

Comment: in your answer you are using `findOne()` not `findAll()` to get the color against the `person_id`, which shows there is only one color saved against a person? i added an answer below see if that helps.

Comment: i hope you are not saving comma separated value in the `id_color` in the `persons` table otherwise you should have a junction table to have one-to-many relation if i am not wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works but I don't think it is the best:

```
public function personsList()
{
    $persons = \app\models\Persons::find()->orderBy('name_person')->all();
    $personsList = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($persons, 'id_person', function($persons) {
        $color = \app\models\Colors::findOne(['id_color' => $persons->id_color]);
        $name_color = $color->name_color;
        return $persons->name_person . ' - ' . $name_color;
    });

    return $personsList;
}
```

I hope someone can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined the relations between the models a much cleaner and optimized way could be like below.

I assume you a relation with th name `getColor()` inside  your `Persons` model. Change your function `personsList()` to the following.

```
public function personsList() {
     $persons = rsons::find()->with('color')->orderBy('name_person')->all();
     return ArrayHelper::map($persons, 'id_person', function($persons) {
          return $persons->name_person . ' - ' . $persons->color->name_color;
     });
}
```

The above will return you an array like below

```
{
    "1": "omer aslam - red",
    "2": "irfan ashraf - blue",
    "3": "shaban khan - pink",
    "4": "rana touqeer - red",
    "5": "sajjad - blue"
}
```

### EDIT

If you are saving multiple colors against the person which does not look the case as you have no junction table and the color is saved against the `person` in the `persons` table, but anyhow if it is `one-to-many` then change the callback function inside the `ArrayHelper::map()` to below so that it shows you all the colors associated to the person.

```
function($persons) {
    return $persons->name_person . '-' . implode(",",\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getColumn($persons->color, 'name_color'));
}
```